# Difference between OpenAM AND ADFS

Tags: adfs, openam

I want to know the difference between OpenAM AND ADFS. Could the application tested with openAM will also successfully work with ADFS. I need to know this to put this as I do not have access to ADFS, and I can install opensource OpenAM and simualte SSO flows with it. Or should I test my code against ADFS directly. I could decide on this If I know differences in both.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: If you just want to play with federation I would recommend to you to use Azure Access Control Service (ACS). It easy to configure. Just in literally 5 minutes you can get a functional Security Token Service. While installing and configuring of OpenAM is not a trivial task. Here is a nice blogpost about it with C# WIF-based code example http://blog.chudinov.net/federated-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-with-access-control-service/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of how they handle the federation protocols e.g. WS-Fed and SAML, there is no difference. They both respond to protocol commands. They are both STS.

As to compatibility for applications, it depends on how they are written. ADFS applications would typically use something like WIF which is a .NET C# library, not appropriate for Java.

Also they have different functionality is terms of "add-ons".

Neither ADFS or OpenAM is "free" AFAIK.

Have a look at [IdentityServer3](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/) which is open-source.

Comment: OpenAM is free of charge as long as you build it yourself.

Comment: Why do you think Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) that supports WS-Fed and SAML is "not appropriate" for OpenAM? OpenAM supports same protocols and tokens. It should be nothing to do with .NET / Java. WS-Federation and SAML are not binary technologies. They work over HTTP as a transport in a web environment.

Comment: True - I was coming more from the .NET / Java angle. Have updated the answer.